# TexShop macro query

Tags: texshop

Ok, this is no doubt an embarrassingly dumb question but ....

In TeXShop, when I select the macro "Close Begin/End" I just get an Apple Script error message:

> A “to” can’t go after this “to”.

So what is the correct usage of this macro? The companion "Insert Begin/End" macro works fine.

Comment: What macOS and TeXShop versions are you using? Also, TeXshop has a `Source->Close Current Environment` menu item so that macro isn't needed. Finally, if you have `\begine{yourenv}` directly followed by pressing Esc you will get `\end{yourenv}` on the next line with the cursor between them using Command Completion.

Comment: Latest versions of both OSX and TeXShop. Yes, I knew about the others, so not a mission-critical question! But puzzled by macro behaviour, since it has been part of TeXShop for a fair while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug on this macro. The AppleScript code, which is also available at [this page](http://www2.hawaii.edu/%7Eramonf/TeXShop/CloseBeginEnd.html) has a bug on line 141:             `tell me to  to set environment_name to do shell script`

Replace `tell me to  to set` by `tell me to set`.

You could do this replacement in TeXShop by open the *Macros > Open Macros editor* menu.

After that, suppose your `.tex` code is:

[image]

Note the cursor after `\begin{center}`. Then call this macro. The code become:

[image]

You can find a description of all macros provided by Ramon Figueroa-Centeno for TeXShop at [http://www2.hawaii.edu/~ramonf/TeXShop/index.html](http://www2.hawaii.edu/%7Eramonf/TeXShop/index.html)

Comment: Ahah! Mystery solved. :)